# Understanding comparisons of topologies.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have this proposition,

Let X be a non-empty set and $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ be topologies on X. Then
$\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ if and only if for every $ U \in \tau_1$ and $x \in U$ there exists 
$V = V_x \in \tau_2$ such that $x \in V$
and $V \subset U$.

I am not really getting a grasp for this proposition and I do not understand it intuitively, what is it trying to say?

Comment: It's just saying that t2 is finer than t1. You can think of this as starting with the topology t1, and then we just add more sets to the topology and call the new one t2

Answer (score 2):

We want every open set $U$ (under $\tau_1$) to be open in $\tau_2$ as well (in the inclusion), which means that every point of such $U$ should be an interior point with respect to $\tau_2$, and this is what the condition states exactly.